# Getting a mysql count of rows for each of the last 30 days

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a 3 column table, trying to get a unique count of entries per day for the last 30 days.

```
|RecordNumber|extension|date|
```

I thought I was making progress with this

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS Dates, extension 
   FROM API_phones 
  WHERE date LIKE '%' AND date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
  ORDER BY Dates ASC
```

but I'm not sure how to finish it.

Basically how many entries per day for the last 30 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need count per day then use the following:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS Dates, count(*) as count 
   FROM API_phones 
  WHERE date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
Group by
  Dates
  ORDER BY Dates ASC
```

If you need it per day per extension you can try the following:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS Dates, extension, count(*) as count 
   FROM API_phones 
  WHERE date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
Group by
  Dates, extension
  ORDER BY Dates ASC
```

Comment: Beautiful... Works perfect 100% what I wanted.

Comment: @user3512531 please accept this as an answer so other stackoverflow users can focus on other unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

if you need  the number of entries  for each day you should use count(*) and group by

```
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS Dates, count(*) num_entries 
   FROM API_phones 
   WHERE date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() 
   GROUP BY Dates
   ORDER BY Dates ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS Dates, COUNT(*) AS entry_count
   FROM API_phones 
  WHERE date LIKE '%' AND date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
  GROUP BY Dates
  ORDER BY Dates ASC
```